# Undocumented property `terminal` of `readline` interface

Tags: javascript, node.js

The core module `readline`'s interface [has a property `terminal`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/readline/interface.js#L240), which is accessible from the outside.

However, I couldn't find this property anywhere on the [documentation for `readline`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v17.x/api/readline.html). I encountered it, because a package on npm internally used it. Maybe I overlooked the related part in documentation?

Is this property safe to use (part of the public API, someone forgot to add it), or do I have to duplicate the code producing the default on the outside, pass that in, and save the result?

Comment: "*Is this property safe to use (part of the public API)*" - no. "*someone forgot to add it*" - maybe. But you'd have to ask the author/maintainers of the module for that, not us at StackOverflow. I suggest to open an issue in the nodejs repo.

Comment: Looking at the code and the docs again, I'd say they *probably* forgot to add it - none of the instance properties are documented, but all the properties that are available also as options are probably stable.